# how to improve query performance for a 40gb mysql isam table?

Tags: mysql

We have a big table about 40gb table (MYD + MYI file total), with all the indexable column indexed, including composite indexes of commonly joined columns, but the query performance is still excruciatingly slow. What else can I do to improve the query performance? Our server is hyperthreaded quad core with 8gb ram running linux.
Thanks a lot in advance.

here is a simple query using the table:

```
select sq.sq_search_id, count(ssh.sq_search_hit_id)
from sq_search sq
inner join sq_search_hit ssh 
use index(by_sq_search_id) on sq.sq_search_id = ssh.sq_search_id
where sq.search_ts >= '2011-09-07'group by sq.sq_search_id
```

here is the explain result:

1. 1, 'SIMPLE', 'ssh', 'ALL', 'by_sq_search_id', '', '', '', 149683523, 'Using temporary; Using filesort'
2. 1, 'SIMPLE', 'sq', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'lims.ssh.sq_search_id', 1, 'Using where'

224 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 359.754 sec

David

Comment: manual sharding is always an option if the data scheme allows it.. but that means you have to refactor all your existing clients. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)

Answer (score 0):

With that much information we cannot really give you advices, just very basic ones:

- More RAM
- Use SSD
- Shard the database if possible
- If the DB is read heavy use Master-Slave configuration.

**Update**

1, 'SIMPLE', 'ssh', '**ALL**', 'by_sq_search_id'

That's a full table scan right there, I hope I don't have to explain how *bad* that is.

Is it faster if you remove the index hint? Is that the right index? Have you tried to qualify the table name for it?

Comment: what information do you need? I can provide the info, thanks!

Comment: what's the bottleneck? CPU or disk? `cpustat/mpstat/iostat`. do you have unused indexes? is sharding possible?

Comment: bottleneck could be disk. I do have unused indices, and sharding probably won't be an option.

Comment: the performance overall is good, only when there is a join using that big table. Are you saying the unused indices could also be a factor here?

Comment: I know how bad it is :-), but it IS the right index to use, with or without index hint give me the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html), you should expand the size of [key_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size). Here you have more info:

> Index blocks for MyISAM tables are buffered and are shared by all
>   threads. key_buffer_size is the size of the buffer used for index
>   blocks. The key buffer is also known as the key cache.

Try to make all your indexes (key_buffer_size) fit in memory.

Also, is there an index on `sq.search_ts` and `ssh.sq_search_id`?

Comment: there isn't an index for sq.search_ts, there is one for ssh.sq_search_id. but even with this query: select sq.sq_search_id, count(ssh.sq_search_hit_id), sq.search_ts, sq.peptideid_sample_run_id from sq_search sq
inner join sq_search_hit ssh on sq.sq_search_id = ssh.sq_search_id
where sq.sq_search_id >= 47000
group by sq.sq_search_id the results returned in 12 seconds. currently, key_buffer size is set to 1G, with 8GB RAM installed, but the MYI file itself is about 20GB

Comment: Wow, that's a big index file. Anyway, create an index on sq.search_ts It's on the where clause, it will be used. Check this article for table_cache, maybe you can improve something:http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/